# View and Data API Toolbar and Navigation Manipulation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

After searching through the API docs, I can't figure out how to access and manipulate specific toolbar elements. I need to remove several nav tools, like 'Pan' or 'FirstPersonTool'.
[image]

Even using trusty 'ole JQuery `remove()` doesn't work.

```
$('#toolbar-orbitTools').remove(); //"Fails"
```

Here is my initializer code:

```
 var token = gon.token;
 var urn   = gon.urn;
 function getToken() {
   return token;
 }

 var viewerApp;
 var options = {
   env: 'AutodeskProduction',
   accessToken: getToken(),
   refreshToken: getToken(),
 };

 var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;

 var callback = function() {
   viewerApp = new Autodesk.A360ViewingApplication('viewer');
   viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D);
   viewerApp.loadDocumentWithItemAndObject(documentId);
 };

 Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, callback);
```

Answer (score 3):

I know of a way to remove the toolbar tools that you don't need through the use of an extension. The simplest way will be to go over the code of the extension located here. http://viewer.autodesk.io/node/gallery/#/viewer?id=57cb8d7cf818a81c0c8502fb

See attached image so you have a better reference of the Extension named Control Selector to remove the toolbar options you will not like.

[image: Extension Control Selector]

Now if you would like to start your viewer without any toolbar options and add custom buttons to use the functionality of the ones you want, that can be done as well. Change this line

```
viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D);
```

change it to the following:

```
viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D);
```

Comment: To be clear; I have to create an extension that rebuilds the toolbar with only the controls I want?

Comment: No, you use js and css to hide the controls you don't want, take a look at the code that Jaime pointed out. Whether you place your code in an extension or not is up to you. You however have to make sure the controls have actually been already created once the hidding code is run, otherwise it will have no effect.